# Android Things: Raspberry Pi Gamepad usb

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, android-things, gamepad

Someone knows how to implement the use of a usb gamepad for the raspberry pi in android things, I've tried all of UsbManager, InputDevice, but I could not make it work.

https://developer.android.com/training/game-controllers/controller-input
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host

Comment: Does it not just work? Android has support for a handful of usb input devices in the framework.

Answer (score 0):

In principle Android Things should work the same as Android, so, most gamepads work just as HID devices and register the buttons as key presses, so you just need to override onKeyDown / onKeyUp.

In the case of a joystick with multiple positions you have a MotionEvent and you can override onGenericMotionEvent.

I know it is one of your links, but this what I have always done to add gamepad support on Android: https://developer.android.com/training/game-controllers/controller-input

Comment: The problem is that the raspberry does not detect the gamepad, so I'm looking for alternatives.

Comment: maybe it is a controller problem. I did use one a while ago to control a robot car and it worked fine, and it was a very cheap controller.

Comment: that weird, I'm using a ps3 usb control, I'll try to get another control to see if the error is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Genuine SIXAXIS/Dualshock3 gamepads should work on most Linux-based OSes including Raspberry Pi and Android because they are supported through the hid-sony kernel module. Sometimes you need a newer kernel version to support newer devices, but DS3 support is old enough that you shouldn't need to update anything.

Is your gamepad a genuine Sony device? If it's a third party gamepad it probably won't work through hid-sony. It *might* still work as a generic HID gamepad.

You can check if Linux detects the device:

```
ls /dev/input/js*
```

"Joystick" devices on linux show up as `/dev/input/js0`, `js1`, `js2`, etc. If you don't see anything here it means the OS doesn't think it's a gamepad and it probably isn't going to work.

If Linux sees it but you can't access it through Android Things, I don't know what the issue is.